# Typewriter Sequence and a.e convergence

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence of functions $(f_{n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ as following:
$$f_{1}=\chi_{[0,1)}$$ $$f_{2}=\chi_{[0, \frac{1}{2})},f_{3}=\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1)} $$ $$f_{4}=\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{4})},f_{5}=\chi_{[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2})},f_{6}=\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4})},f_{7}=\chi_{[\frac{3}{4},1)}$$
$$........$$
$$f_{2^{k-1}}=\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2^{k-1}})},....................,f_{2^k-1}=\chi_{[\frac{k}{2^{k-1}},1)}$$ We know that this sequence converges in measure at the zero function and that it fails to converge pointwise at the same function (or any other). Also we know that we can find a subsequence that converges a.e to the zero function (and one that converges to $g=1$). My question is, if we can construct explicitly the subsequence ( say $(f_{n_{k}})_{k\in\Bbb N})$ that converges to the zero function. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $f_1, f_3, \cdots, f_{2^k - 1}, \cdots$ converges to $0$ everywhere.

By the way, I don't think there is a subsequence that converges a.e. to $g = 1$.

Comment: I agree with "by the way..."

Answer (score 1):

$(f_{2^{k}}) \to $ almost everywhere. It is easy to see that there exits $a_n \to \infty$ with $a_nf_n \to 0$ in measure. If a subsequence of $f_n$ tends to $1$ almost everywhere we get a contradiction to the fact that $\int a_n f_n \to 0$.

Comment: would you describe further how $(f_{2^{k}})$ looks like? Thank you!