# Question on sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n(x)$ be a sequence of functions defined on an closed and bounded interval of the real number system. Is it possible that each $f_n(x)$ is integrable but $f_n(x)$ doesn't converge for any $x$ in the domain ?

My thoughts are if $f_n(x)$ diverge to infinity then $f_n(x)$ may not be integrable. But what about if the sequence $f_n(x)$ is bounded but oscillatory. I can't find any clue. Also the integral may be improper one. So what is the answer then ?

Any hint will be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: There is a well known sequence for this kind of problems : the [typewriter sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402184/typewriter-sequence-and-a-e-convergence). The sequence of integrals even converge to $0$ in this example. $f_n(x) = \mathbf1_{[\sin(n)-0.1,\sin(n)+0.1]}$ is another example, but the sequence of integrals does not converge to $0$ here.

Comment: That the $f_n$ diverge to infinity and that each $f_n$ be integrable have nothing to do with one another. The latter is a condition on the individual elements, the former on the sequence as a whole. As pointed out below, $f_n=n$ diverges to infinity and yet each individual function is integrable, much like how the fact that the sequence of real numbers $x_n=n$ diverges to infinity does not contradict the fact that each individual term is a finite number.

Comment: Yeah ! I get it.