# Show that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Suppose $f_n$ are $L^1$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$ the measure $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon\}$ goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$. I want to show that $f_n$ converges to $f$ a.e.

This seems to be trivial and here is my argument:
Suppose not, then there exists $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon_0$ on a set of positive measure, which is a contradiction.

I wonder if above argument is true?

Comment: You have not used $f_n\in L_1$. You would make the claim that convergence in probability implies convergence almost surely. This is not true.

Comment: "Suppose not, then *there are some* $\delta>0$ *and some measurable set* $U$ *such that* $m(U)>\delta$ *and such that for all* $x\in U$ *there is some* $\varepsilon>0$ *such that for all* $N$ *there is some* $n\ge N$ *such that* $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert>\varepsilon$." How did you continue?

Comment: As it is  stated, the result is false. Please, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412091/the-typewriter-sequence/1412099

Comment: You ca also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402184/typewriter-sequence-and-a-e-convergence

Answer (score 2):

The proposition is false and it is impossible to prove. If the measure is finite, then the given condition means that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure. Remark: It is well-known that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure implies that the exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ of $(f_n)$ such that $f_{n_k}\rightarrow f$ a.e. as $k\rightarrow \infty$. If I remember correctly, this result is due to Vitali.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149777/269063 gives the standard counterexample.